# Timer Function creates pause at the start of process not the end like I want

Tags: swift, loops

I want to have a looping event with a timer triggered instantly when a button is held down. But the timer function pauses for two seconds before auctioning the 'pulse', my (maybe slightly naive) assumption was the timer would pause after the action before starting the loop again.

Any idea how can I get the below to give the 2 second pause after the pulse instead of before?

```
@IBAction func flashDown(_ sender: Any) {
    // Touch Down Button

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in

        print("Pulse")

    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you just do the action before you invoke the timer?

Comment: The 2 second pause is part of the loop, so my thought are anything outside the Timer.scheduledTimer would not get repeated.

Comment: I meant, in addition to the timer.

Comment: so you mean remove the pause from the timer function and add a new pause function after the action?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by removing the pause. I meant: execute the action first, then start the timer with the same action. In your example, add another `print("Pulse")`  before `Timer.scheduledTimer`... EDIT: Never mind - even a better solution below

Answer (score 0):

You can use another initializer of `Timer` and add it to the `RunLoop` by yourself.

```
    @IBAction func flashDown(_ sender: Any) {
        let now = Date()
        let timer = Timer(fire: now, interval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in
            print("Pulse")
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OOPer's answer is nice, but actually you can just call the `fire` method of the timer instance. This method can be called at any time without interrupting its regular firing schedule.

```
@IBAction func flashDown(_ sender: Any) {
    // Touch Down Button

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in
        print("Pulse")
    }
    timer.fire()
}
```